Renewal reward process's reward tail probability
Suppose we are given a dice with $K$ faces, denoted by $k=1,\dots,K$, where the probability of realizing a face $k$ is $p_k\in[0,1]$ with $\sum_{k=1,\dots,K}p_k=1$.
Now, we roll the dice repetitively. When a face $k$ is realized, we need to wait for a positive random time $S_k$ before rolling again. The question is: given a total time budget $B>0$, how many times have we rolled a particular face $k^*$?
This problem can be formalized as a renewal-reward process, whose holding/waiting time is a sequence $\{S_{k_i,i}\}_{i\geq 1}$ of IID random variable with mean $\mathbb{E}[S_{k_i,i}]=\sum_{k=1,\dots,K}[p_k\mathbb{E}[S_k]]\in(0,\infty)$. The stopping time $\tau=\inf\{t=1,2,\dots\colon J_t=\sum_{i=1,\dots,t} S_{k_i,i}>B\}=\sum_{t=1,2,\dots} 1_{S_{t-1}\leq B}$. Then, the reward is defined as the number of times when face $k^*$ is realized. Formally, the reward is $\tau_{k^*}:=\sum_{t=1,2,\dots} 1_{S_{t-1}\leq B} 1_{k_t=k^*}$.
By Applied Probability and Queues by Asmussen Eq.6.2 (Wald equation), we have that $\mathbb{E}[\tau_{k^*}]=p_{k^*}\mathbb{E}[\tau]$, and by Prop.6.2, we have that $\mathbb{E}[\tau]\leq \frac{B}{\mathbb{E}[S_{x_1,1}]} + \frac{\mathbb{E}[S_{x_1,1}^2]}{\mathbb{E}[S_{x_1,1}]^2}$.
My question is are there exponentially-decaying tail concentration inequalities for the reward $\tau_{k^*}=\sum_{t=1,2,\dots} 1_{S_{t-1}\leq B} 1_{k_t=k^*}$, in the form of $\mathbb{P}[\tau_{k^*}>\epsilon \mathbb{E}[\tau_{k^*}]]\leq \exp[-\dots]$? Here, let's assume that each face's $S_k$ is a positive sub-exponential random variable, which means that $\forall \lambda\colon|\lambda|<\frac{1}{\alpha_k}\colon\mathbb{E}[\exp[\lambda S_k] \leq \exp[\frac{\lambda^2 v_k^2}{2}]$ (Def.5.1 here).
I have tried to construct a Martingale $\sum_{t=1,2,\dots} 1_{S_{t-1}\leq B} (1_{k_t=k^*}-p_{k^*})$ and apply Azuma-Hoeffding. However, I am not sure how to relate the fixed discrete time $N$ in Azuma Hoeffding and the random stopping time $\tau$ in our problem.
